# Minimum window substring using python containing substr in any order

Tags: python, algorithm, strings

> Given an array of unique characters `arr` and a string `str`, implement a function `getShortestUniqueSubstring` that finds the smallest substring of `str` containing all the characters in `arr`. Return `""` (empty string) if such a substring doesn’t exist.

[This algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459653/how-to-find-smallest-substring-which-contains-all-characters-from-a-given-string) is used.

```
import collections
import sys

def get_shortest_unique_substring(substring, string):
  def trim_left(substring, window, count):
    ''' find how much left pointer can be moved in a window where all substring is present'''
    for left, c in enumerate(window):
      if c in count and count[c] > 1:
        count[c] -= 1
      elif c not in count:
        continue
      else:
        return left
    return 0

  substring = set(substring)
  ''' validating input '''
  if not substring or not string:
    return ""
  if len(substring) == len(string) and substring == set(string):
    return string

  window, min_window, min_window_len = [], [], sys.maxint
  left, right, count = 0, 0, collections.Counter()
  # to check if the initial minimum window has been found which has all the substring
  substr_found = set(substring)

  for right, c in enumerate(string):
    if c in substring:
      count[c] += 1
      if c in substr_found:
        substr_found.remove(c)
      # window has been found and now trim left pointer as much as possible maintaining the invariant that substr is still present between left and right pointers
      if not substr_found:
        left += trim_left(substring, string[left:right+1], count)
        # update the minimum window
        if right - left + 1 < min_window_len:
          min_window_len, min_window = right - left + 1, string[left:right+1]
        # we can't find better window than the length of substr
        if len(min_window) == len(substring):
          return "".join(min_window)
  return "".join(min_window)
```

Comment: It would be much easier to evaluate if you included comments...

Comment: @Snowbody that's part of the code review.

Comment: @Snowbody: added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

Interesting algorithm.  I looked over it and tried to find a bit simpler of a way.    Basically, I implemented the modified version with a dictionary.  The dictionary stores the data in the formation `char:index`.  Every time we run into a relevant character we update the dictionary.  This eliminates all need for back tracking via `trim_left`. Every time we updated our dictionary of character locations, we would get a string by finding the `min` and `max` of the dictionary. If that string is smaller, then we assign it to the `smallest` variable.

## Performance

Typically the newer version performs a lot faster.  This can be explained by referring to big O notation.  Yours, because of back tracking, performs at `O(n^2)` or worse. However, the newer version doesn't back track so much, and it sticks to only modifying one dictionary so the new version worst case scenario is `O(n)` efficiency. (Or, to be more specific, it is O(nm) where n is the length of your string and m is the length of the substring; however there is a very logical limit to the length of substring m, so it will probably never be worse than O(64n) [note: we convert the `string` to a `set` to remove duplicates]).

## New Code

```
def newShortest(subString, string):
  myChars = set(subString)
  smallest = ""
  current={}
  for i, char in enumerate(string):
    if char in myChars:
      current[char] = i
      if len(current) == len(myChars):
        temp = string[current[min(current,key=current.get)]:current[max(current,key=current.get)]+1]
        if len(temp) < len(smallest) or len(smallest) == 0:
          smallest = temp
  return smallest
```

## Code used to time your version vs modified version

I switched out the `args` for smaller and larger sizes:

```
import time

args = ["hello","I would like to all over you hehhhhhkkkkkkkkkklo"]

def timeIt(func,args):
  then = time.time()
  for _ in range(10000):
    func(*args)
  print("{} timing: {:.2f}".format(func.__name__, time.time()-then))

timeIt(newShortest,args)
timeIt(get_shortest_unique_substring,args)
```

Comment: Can you provide a example with some words?

Comment: @nomanpouigt Do you mean something like looking for smallest substring of `hello` in a Wikipedia article? I've also updated the explanation so it may make more sense now.

Comment: I mean substr:xyz in string:txyuxyyzxyz ?

Comment: Returns `yzx` and is done with 35% faster(as input gets larger the efficiency difference will increase).  If you are wondering, yours returns the same thing.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I just want to understand your algorithm and it would be better if you can explain it with an example.

Comment: It iterates over every character, whenever it sees a useful one (like `(z,y,z)`, we update the dictionary.  So our dictionary looks like `{"z":2, "y":1, "z": 3}`.  Then we fetch the string difference between the highest value and the lowest value.  So, in this example, it'd be `[1:3]`.  Then we get `string[1:3]`  Then if that is `<` our current smallest's length, we will then update the string.  Optimally you can remove the `min` and `max` function... but that would expand the code by a bit.